# Can't submit asp.net c# form values after returning to edit that page from confirmation screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, session-variables

**Background**

I have two asp.net c# forms and then when I press the 'Add' button on the first page, I send the user to a second confirmation page where I pass the values.

On the confirmation page, there is an edit button that uses server.transfer to return the user back to the original form. I use !ispostback to assign the original page form fields with the session variables.

**Problem**

The problem is although the values are in each form field and dropdown menu correctly on original page (that I have pressed "edit" to get back to, when I press the 'add' button a second time to confirm this page, it does not see or post the values from this original form back to the confirmation page unless I manually change each field (it won't post 'remembered' fields back). What could be the issue the second time or more doing this that prevents the form data to send again to the confirmation page if no changes are made to any of the form entries?

**Here is the first page code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     //   var userData = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserData"];
if(!IsPostBack)
{ 


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["name"] as string))
        {
            name.Text = Session["name"].ToString();
            contenttype.SelectedValue = Session["contenttype"].ToString();
            numOfWords.SelectedValue = Session["numOfWords"].ToString();
            keyword.Text = Session["keyword"].ToString();
            rank.SelectedValue = Session["rank"].ToString();
            specialinstructions.Text = Session["specialinstructions"].ToString();

        }
}

    }
```

**Here is the confirmation page code behind:**

```
  if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);
            this.lblConfirmationHeader.Text = "Project Confirmation";
            this.lblProjectTitle.Text = Request.Form["name"];
            this.lblContentType.Text = Request.Form["contenttype"];
            this.lblnumberOfWords.Text = Request.Form["numOfWords"];
            this.lblKeywordFocus.Text = Request.Form["keyword"];
            this.lblWritersRank.Text = Request.Form["rank"];
            this.lblSpecialInstructions.Text = Request.Form["specialinstructions"];

            Session["name"] = Request.Form["name"];
            Session["contenttype"] = Request.Form["contenttype"];
            Session["numOfWords"] = Request["numOfWords"];
            Session["keyword"] = Request.Form["keyword"];
            Session["rank"] = Request.Form["rank"];
            Session["specialinstructions"] = Request.Form["specialinstructions"];

        }
```

Comment: I can't think of an answer to this, but I have a handy workaround in my mind. What about allowing the user to edit the data in the second view on the click of a button?

Comment: That may work. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: What does the code for the Add button look like? I would assume you'd need to update the session values there just prior to calling the confirmation page.